# Approximate solution to linear system in Armadillo library

Tags: c++, armadillo

Does anyone know how the Armadillo library finds an approximate solution to a linear system with non-invertible A matrix (Ax=b). The function under consideration is *solve(x,A,b)* .

Thanks in advance

Comment: It appears the library is open source: Have you tried looking at the code or debugging it? Did you have trouble understanding it? Can you be specific about the parts that you don't understand?

Comment: Hi, you are right. I'll try it, but i guess it is not going to be clear, because i don't know the theory behind. But still i am gonna check it. Thanks

Comment: I looked at it, but since i am not a software engineer, i could not understand much. Actually for me the theory is important, that is, mathematical procedure. What approach it uses to get a solution with singular A matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By inspection of the file `include\armadillo_bits\glue_solve_meat.hpp`, it seems that for a non-square matrix, Armadillo uses the LAPACK method [`gelsd`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/double/dgelsd.f) (least-squares solution based on SVD). If the settings option `solve_opts::fast` is supplied, it tries first [`gels`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/double/dgels.f) (QR/LQ decomposition) and if that fails, it resorts to SVD as well.